# Wait for one React CSS animation to end before starting another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup, react-transition-group

I'm using React and the [CSSTransitionGroup](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group) component to switch between two sets of `members` in my app's state. Its state contains the `members`, each of which has a flag to say whether they're a real member of not. It also contains a flag to keep track of which type of member we're viewing:

```
this.state = {
      viewMembers: true,
      members: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Jim",
          isMember: true
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "John",
          isMember: false
        }
    ]
}
```

In my `render` function I map over this array, and only show members corresponding with the view state (i.e. if `viewMembers` is `true`, I only show members where `isMember` is `true`, and vice versa). For each member I return a table `<tr>`. The `map` function is wrapped in a `CSSTransitionGroup` tag to fade in the table rows. This all works fine - please see working code here: [jsfiddle.net/d9cfh4zg/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/d9cfh4zg/1/).

My issue is that it currently fades in the new state before fading out the old one, giving it a slightly janky quality. How can I allow existing rows to fade out before fading in the new ones?

Comment: Problem is that your rows creating with a height and just not being showed. You can try to animate tr heights with the opacity.

Comment: @GluePear please check out the editted answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
const styles = {
    fontFamily: "sans-serif"
  };

  const CSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

  class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        viewMembers: true,
        members: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "Jim",
            isMember: true
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "John",
            isMember: false
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: "Sarah",
            isMember: false
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: "Mary",
            isMember: true
          }
        ]
      };
        this.refreshState = true;
    }

    changeViewState(state) {
      this.refreshState = false;
      setTimeout(() => {

        if (state === "members") {
          this.setState({ viewMembers: true });
          if(!this.refreshState)
          {
           this.changeViewState(state);
           this.refreshState = true;
           }
        } else {
          this.setState({ viewMembers: false });
          if(!this.refreshState)
          {
            this.changeViewState(state);
            this.refreshState = true;
           }
        }
      }, 500);

    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div style={styles}>
          <h4>Members</h4>
          <ul>
            <li onClick={() => this.changeViewState("members")}>View Members</li>
            <li onClick={() => this.changeViewState("non-members")}>
              View Non-members
            </li>
          </ul>
          <MembersTable
            viewMembers={this.state.viewMembers}
            members={this.state.members}
            refreshState = {this.refreshState}

          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  const MembersTable = (props) =>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <strong>Id</strong>
          </td>
          <td>
            <strong>Name</strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <CSSTransitionGroup
                component="tbody"
                transitionName="fade"
                transitionAppear={true}
                transitionAppearTimeout={500}
                transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
                >
        {props.members.map(member => {
          if (
            (props.viewMembers && member.isMember && props.refreshState) ||
            (!props.viewMembers && !member.isMember && props.refreshState)
          ) {
            return (
              <tr key={member.id}>
                <td>
                  {member.id}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {member.name}
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          }
        })}
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
    </table>;

  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I have added a `refreshState` variable and updated it in the `setTimeout` callback function which is added in the `changeViewState` function.

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9cfh4zg/2/)

hope this helps.